# How to use BouncyCastle Provider in JRE 1.4

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, bouncycastle, keystore, java-security

I am making web service call in java 1.4 Environment. Recently Web Service server's certificate changed to SSL 2.

After changing certificate to SSL 2 when I make Service call from my application, I got below Exception.

```
 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: Certificate signature validation failed
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:84)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:542)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:189)

Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11 
Signature not available
    at java.security.Security.getEngineClassName(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Security.getEngineClassName(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Signature.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(Unknown Source)
    ... 61 more"
```

Algorithm used by the certificate is "SHA256WITHRSA" for this OID is not available in JRE1.4.

Adding BouncyCastle Provider resolves this issue? If then How to install / use it?

Please suggest.

Comment: You're 13 years behind with 1.4, and you may have no choice but to upgrade.

Comment: I have no choice to upgrade java version and It is said that Javav1.4.2 supports SSL 2 certificate.

Comment: By adding bouncycastle provider will it resolve? can anyone suggest? java.security.Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

Comment: Yep. Adding BouncyCastly Provider solved my problem.